# Ways of proving normal distribution (with a view towards Selberg's central limit theorem)

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, analytic-number-theory, gaussian, probabilistic-number-theory

Given an random variable $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with finite mean $\mu$ and finite, positive variance $\sigma^2$, let $X = \frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}$ be the renormalization with mean $0$ and variance $1$. what are some general techniques for showing that $Y$ has a normal distribution? That is,
$$P(X\leqslant a) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^a e^{-t^2/2}\,dt.$$

The standard technique I know is to compute the moments or [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) and then use the fact that the normal distribution is characterized by its moments/cumulants. Are there any other general techniques, and what are their advantages and disadvantages?

---

The motivation for this question is number theoretic (as with [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102964/convergence-of-moments-implies-convergence-to-normal-distribution)), hence the number theory tags. Specifically, the motivating theorem is Selberg's central limit theorem (first published in [Tsang's thesis](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2633927), see also [this article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3832861) of Radziwill-Soundararajan) which states that for large $T$, the real valued random variable on $[T,2T]$ given by $t \mapsto \log|\zeta(\tfrac12 + it)|$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{2}{\log\log T}$.

Both the proofs I know of (Selberg's original proof, and that of Radziwill-Soundararajan) use the method of moments. Morally speaking, the analytic-number-theoretic input goes into showing that the contributions from the zeros of zeta can be controlled, and hence at least for the distributional question with $t \in [T,2T]$,
$$\log|\zeta(\tfrac12 + it)| \simeq \Re\sum_{p\leqslant T^{o(1)}} \frac{1}{p^{1/2 + it}}.$$
One can then compute the moments of the right hand side and show that as $T \to \infty$, the moments appropriately normalized converge to the moments of a standard Gaussian.

The hope is to see if there's a way to prove Selberg's CLT in a situation where the moments are harder to compute, and so the method of moments may not be tractable.

Comment: Other methods to prove central limit theorems include Fourier-analytic methods, Stein's method, and the Lindeberg exchange method: see my lecture notes at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/ .  However, in analytic number theoretic situations moments are pretty much the only thing we can compute with much accuracy, so we are still mostly stuck with moment methods for now.

Comment: There is also a heat equation proof by Petrovsky and Kolmogorov: see link: https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/downloads/w3763840s and here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280186/gaussian-distribution-maximum-entropy-and-the-heat-equation and on the same spirit information theory: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182752/central-limit-theorem-via-maximal-entropy

Comment: @ThomasKojar: Thanks for the references!

Comment: @TerryTao: Thanks for the reference! I wasn't too hopeful something could be done in my specific setup, since I wasn't even able to compute the moments, but I figured it was worth a shot to ask a wide question like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple books about ways to characterize the normal distribution. For instance, Bryc’s [book](https://homepages.uc.edu/%7Ebrycwz/probab/charakt/charakt.pdf) starts with Herschel-Maxwell’s theorem:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables whose joint distribution is rotationally invariant, then $X$ and $Y$ are both normal.

He immediately notes that one can strengthen this to Polya’s theorem:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, and rotations of $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$ leave the distribution of $X$ invariant, then $X$
> and $Y$ are both normal.

Perhaps somewhere in such books you’ll find a characterization that avoids moments but is number-theoretically tractable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer/reference! This book seems to comprehensively answer the main probability question. I'll leave the question open (in the sense of not accepting an answer) for a few days, in case someone wants to give an answer focusing on the (dis/)advantages of a particular method -- otherwise will accept your answer after that.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the information-theoretic method; see [Linnik](https://doi.org/10.1137/1104028) (1959), [Barron](https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176992632) (1986), etc.  Oliver Johnson has written an [entire book](https://doi.org/10.1142/p341) on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!